# Сохранение и использование данных многомерных массивов - C# (сериализация)

Tags: c#, массивы, сериализация, десериализация

Добрый день!

В windos form через текстбоксы вводятся и редактируются данные для 4х многомерных массивов.

Необходимо по завершении работы, чтобы все элементы массивов сохранили свое текущее значение, а при новом запуске программы подгружали последние данные.

Поискал решение, на глаза попалась сериализация.
Попробовал бинарную сериализацию. Мало что получилось.

```
Код:

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    namespace CityStatic
    {
        [Serializable]
class Mass
{
    public uint[,,,,,] massive { get; set; }
    public uint[,,,,,] massive1 { get; set; }
    public uint[,,,,,] massive2 { get; set; }
    public uint[,,,,,] massive3 { get; set; }


    public Mass(uint[,,,,,] massive, uint[,,,,,] massive1, uint[,,,,,] massive2,
        uint[,,,,,] massive3, uint[,,,,,])
    {
    //???
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    //Создание массива
    //--------------------



    Mass[,,,,,] massive = new Mass[10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11];

    Mass[,,,,,] massive1 = new Mass[10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11];
    Mass[,,,,,] massive2 = new Mass[10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11];
    Mass[,,,,,] massive3 = new Mass[10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11];

    /*
    здесь программа пользовательского записи данных в массивы путем ввода в текстбоксы, при нажатии на одну из 4х кнопок относит запись в один из 4х массивов */

    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 


    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("mass.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) // здесь все красное
    {

    formatter.Serialize(fs, massive); // здесь тоже

    }
```

}

Comment: Так вопрос в чём?

Comment: Пространство имён открыли? `using System.IO;` Именно в том файле, где делаете сериализацию. Или у вас вообще всё в куче в одном файле?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как сохранить данные нескольких многомерных массивов? У меня все в куче в одном файле, планировалась небольшая программка, но со временем она выросла как снежный ком

Comment: Положи свои массивы в другой массив. Сериализатор съест и выплюнет тебе файл. Обратно сериализовать  будешь тоже не забудь что у тебя массив массивов.

Answer (score 0):

Простой и универсальный способ сериализации. Может сериализировать вообще все. Хоть масив масивов, которые хранят еще 10 вложенных массивов :)

При этом ловит IO ошибки. 
Пользуйся вот так:

```
List<Cookie> asdf = new List<Cookie>();

//сериализация
Serializer.Save("data.bin", asdf);

//десериализация
asdf = Serializer.Load<List<Cookie>>("data.bin");
```

Код класса:

```
public static class Serializer
{
    public static void Save(string filePath, object objToSerialize)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                bin.Serialize(stream, objToSerialize);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
    }

    public static T Load<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
    {
        T rez = new T();

        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                rez = (T) bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }

        return rez;
    }
}
```